# What is the odd Fourier extension of $\sin x \cos(2x)$?

Tags: calculus, complex-numbers, fourier-series

odd half range extension of

$$f(x) = \sin x \cos(2x)\text{ with limits $0$ to $\pi$}$$

Comment: @Emmi91 : you need to use $\LaTeX$ or MathJax (?) or something similar to make your question readable.  I can tell you that in an odd half range extension, there is never a constant term, that is, you don't need $a_0$.  I also think the complex-numbers tag doesn't belong unless you show how complex numbers can help do the integrals.  Also, the $\sin(3x-\sin x)$ factor is definitely incorrect; you shouldn't have to deal with anything that nasty.

Comment: okay, can you direct me to the latex guide

Comment: Im essentially trying to get the odd half range extension of sinxcos(2x)

Comment: @Emmi91 : I don't know of a gook $\LaTeX$ guide.  See the link below regarding MathJax, which I know nothing about.

Comment: Did you mean "expansion" rather than "extension"?

Comment: Or "extention"?  (I haven't seen that spelling before.  I'm familiar with a distinction between "intentional" and "intensional", but not with any such counterpart of "extension".)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The question is perfectly readable as is, but see [MathJax basic tutorial and quick reference](http://meta.math.stackexchange.com/q/5020/75064) for the future.

If I understand "odd half range extension" correctly, you are supposed to extend $f$ to an odd function on $[-\pi,\pi]$, and then find the Fourier series of that.

Since $\sin (-x)\cos (-2x)=-\sin x \cos 2x$, the function $f$ is naturally an odd function: we use the same formula $\sin x \cos 2x$ on the whole interval $[-\pi,\pi]$.

Now you have two ways to find the Fourier series

1. Correct but tedious: calculate the coefficients by integrating $\int_{-\pi}^\pi f(x)\sin nx$
2. Clever: use a [product-to-sum identity](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/List_of_trigonometric_identities#Product-to-sum_and_sum-to-product_identities) $$\sin \theta\cos \phi = \frac12 (\sin (\theta+\phi)+\sin(\theta-\phi))$$
   where you will put $\theta=x$ and $\phi=2x$. After some cosmetic simplifications, such as $\sin(-x)=-\sin x$, you have your Fourier series.